# User Profile custom property not updated for all users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, active-directory-import

We want to read data from "State/Province" attribute from AD.

However, this attribute was missing in SharePoint User Profile Service application.
So in order to achieve that, we created a custom property for "State/Province" and mapped through "st" attribute of AD.

After running full synchronisation, only 730 user's "State/Province" property was updated out of 5478 users.
Also, we have checked in the AD and "State/Province" attribute is already updated for all users.

We are working on SharePoint 2016 Enterprise.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to Central Administration->user profile service application->Configure synchronization connections.

Edit the connection to check if you select all the users in the Containers section, and edit the connection filters to check if you exclude certain users to sync.